# How to use QoreProgramLocation class to identify particular location in Qore source code

Tags: qore

I need get statement(s) (i.e.instance of `AbstractStatement` class) related to particular location in file (e.g. *foo.q:150*) so I process somehow parent class (struct) `QoreProgramLocation` which defines two members `file` and `source` (when the latter is often null). It is not clear what is difference. I suspect it might be used when files are included to point both original file and real location in include.

There is also `offset` member. Is it intended for sections used when Qore is embedded in another program (e.g.*Qorus*) ?

```
struct QoreProgramLocation : public QoreProgramLineLocation {
public:
   const char* file;
   const char* source;
   int offset;
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question.

In `QoreProgramLocation`, members are as follows:

- `file`: refers to the label given when parsing the code
- `source`: refers to the actual file name or path of the source code (if the label does not provide this info)
- `offset`: the offset of the code in `source`

So `source` and `offset` are only given if there are multiple code objects defined in the same file.

In case of one code object in one file, then `file` is the set, `source` is `nullptr`, `offset` is 0, and the line number is taken directly from `start_line` and `end_line`.

In case of multiple code objects in one file, then all members are assigned values, in such cases `start_line` and `end_line` refer to the line number within the code object, and the line number in the file is calculated by adding with `offset`, giving the line number offset within `source`.

For example, in the documentation of the following Qore method:

- [QoreProgram::parse()](https://docs.qore.org/current/lang/html/group__misc__functions.html#ga17bc2cdb62ca121ae990e497e609349d)

describes this case; note that `label` will be set as `file` in `QoreProgramLocation`.

Because `offset` is always 0 when there is no `source`, you can always derive the actual line numbers by using: `start_line + offset` and `end_line + offset`.

I hope this is clear!